# Regex.Split everything inside square brackets []

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm really a n00b when it comes to regular expressions.  I've been trying to Split a string wherever there's a `[----anything inside-----]` for example.

```
string s = "Hello Word my name_is [right now I'm hungry] Julian";
string[] words = Regex.Split( s, "------");
```

The outcome would be  `"Hello Word my name_is "` and `" Julian"`

Comment: have you tried this ? `\[[a-zA-Z1-9]*\]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you want to use is:

```
Regex.Split( s, "\\[.*?\\]" );
```

Square brackets are special characters (specifying a character group), so they have to be escaped with a backslash.  Inside the square brackets, you want any sequence of characters EXCEPT a close square bracket.  There are a couple of ways to handle that.  One is to specify `[^\]]*` (explicitly specifying "not a close square bracket").  The other, as I used in my answer, is to specify that the match is not greedy by affixing a question mark after it.  This tells the regular expression processor not to greedily consume as many characters as it can, but to stop as soon as the next expression is matched.

Comment: And, if you simply want to remove that text, you can use Regex.Replace( s, "\\\[.*?\\\]", String.Empty );

Answer (score 1):

`@"\[.*?\]"` will match the brackets of text

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it:

```
Regex.Split(str, @"\[[^]]*\]");
```