# Split string on sqaure brackets and non brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

This is regex problem
I want to split a string

```
"apple[orange] papya [mango] [grapes]"
```

into this array

```
['apple','[orange]','papaya','[mango]','[grapes]']
```

I have tried like this

```js
console.log(
  "apple[orange] papya [mango] [grapes]".match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
)
```

But it returns only what is inside the brackets

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: is there a space between apple and [orange]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex.Split everything inside square brackets \[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001459/regex-split-everything-inside-square-brackets)

Comment: question updated @KrishnaPrashatt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this regex: `/(\[[^\]]+\])/` it will match open bracket any number of not closing braket and closing bracket, parenthesis is used to capture the match in split.

```js
var input = 'apple[orange] papya [mango] [grapes]';
console.log(input.split(/(\[[^\]]+\])/).filter(s => s.trim()));
```

trim is used to filter out blanks you can also use

```js
var input = 'apple[orange] papya [mango] [grapes]';
var words = input.split(/(\[[^\]]+\])/).map(s => s.trim()).filter(Boolean);
console.log(words);
```

Comment: @Arafath updated the question with explanation and code that will remove spaces around `papya`.